# Deformation of Canonical singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $p: X \rightarrow T$ be a flat family of normal projective  varieties over a variety  $T$. Assume that $X_{t_{0}}=p^{-1}(t_{0})$, for a $t_{0}\in T$, has only canonical singularities of index $1$.  Is there a neighborhood $U$ of $X_{t_{0}}$ such that any variety $X_{t}$ belonging to  $U$ has at worst  canonical singularities?  Any variety is over $\mathbb{C}$ here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the base of the deformation is smooth the answer is *yes*. This was proven by Kawamata in his paper *[Deformations of canonical singularities](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-01/S0894-0347-99-00285-4/)*, Journal of the American Mathematical Society **12** (1999), 85-92.

For the reader's convenience, let me write here the precise statement of Kawamata's result.

> **Theorem (Kawamata).** Let $\pi \colon X \to S$ be a flat morphism from a germ of a variety $(X, \, x_0)$ to a germ of a smooth curve $(S, \, s_0)$, whose special fiber $X_0 = \pi^{-1}(s_0)$ has only canonical singularities. Then $X$ has only canonical singularities. In particular, the fibers $X_s = \pi^{-1}(s)$ have only canonical singularities.

Note that your assumption about the index of the singularities of $X_{0}$ is unnecessary.